# How to use a if clause to ensure it check for 'knowledge' word in the problem?

Tags: python, pycharm

I have been trying to solve/practice the below Exercise (Selenium Webdriver with Python) as i'm new to the programming.

Exercise Summary:

```
Open http://www.wikipedia.org and write NUnit/WebDriver test for the following using
Google Chrome: (12 points)
a. Display on console the number of articles in English and click on “English” link (3 points)
b. Search for Anna University. (3 points)
c. Print the 'Motto in English' part in the console and ensure it has the word 'Knowledge' in
it. (3 points)
d. Ensure that “Shiv Nadar” is listed in notable people section (3 points)
```

-->
Now here i'm not able to write down how to put an if statement to check /ensure it has the word knowledge in it and how to i check the d part as well??

Kindly, help me in understanding.

Comment: Please move your example code from the comments to the question

Comment: @ItamarMushkin the code has been removed..Can someone help me on the  problem please

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean to remove it, but to move it to the question. The code that you tried (and didn't work) is an important part of your question - see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @ItamarMushkin in the question, in the c part i have printed the 'Motto in English' to the python console but im not sure how to ensure or verify that it has the word knowledge in it ?? can you please help

Comment: `if 'Knowledge' in word: print('Motto in English')`

Comment: @furas, it doesnt work..can you please check..
wemotto = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="mw-content-text"]/div/table[2]/tbody/tr[2]/td/i')
print("Motto in English :" +wemotto.text)
if 'knowledge' in wemotto:
    print("knowledge is present in Motto:" +wemotto.text)
else:
    print("knowledge is not present in Motto:" +wemotto.text)

Comment: probably you need `.text` in line `if 'knowledge' in wemotto.text: `